# add two or more attribute on onclick event to datagrid rows

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a datagrid and I have to add two attributes on onclick events, with the code below only second attribute is added, someone could help me?

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "OpenModalBox(" + variable.ToString + ")")
e.Row.Attributes("OnClick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gridview, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much aware of asp.net but you can add like this

Dirty Way

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "OpenModalBox("+variable.ToString + ");Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gridview, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)")
```

Cleaner way

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "OpenModalBox(" + variable.ToString + ")")
  function OpenModalBox(arg){
     // Rest of Code;
  Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gridview, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)"
  }
```